# Why was The Hard Candy poster made in reverse to the plot?

Tags: analysis, posters, hard-candy

Actually I saw *Hard Candy*, it's about Hayley Stark torturing Jeff Kohlver:

[image]

But here in the poster, it shows Hayley Stark standing in a trap instead of Jeff Kohlver:

[image]

Why was The Hard Candy poster made in reverse to the plot?

Comment: Did they get their props from IKEA or what?

Comment: She's the bait.  You generally place bait in a trap to attract the animal you intend to capture, think cheese and a mousetrap.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

She not exactly caught in the trap...she's there to attract a predator to catch him in the trap.

[**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_Candy_(film))

> The film opens with a sexually charged, flirtatious online chat between 14-year-old Hayley Stark and Jeff Kohlver, a photographer in his mid-30s. Jeff and Hayley meet at a coffeehouse, and he takes her back to his apartment. Hayley makes them both screwdrivers and asks him to take photographs. Before he can, Jeff gets dizzy, his vision blurs, and he falls to the floor unconscious.

---

> Hayley explains she has been tracking him and drugged him because she knows he is a pedophile, child rapist, and murderer.

Basically, she's using herself as **bait** in the trap.

[image]